# How to publish my C# winforms solution with an .xml file included

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv, haar-classifier

I have a program (solution) in Visual Studio 2022 and I need to publish it as a setup.exe application. My application is a simple face recognition using the haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml file. I need to publish my C# soultion with this .xml file included.

I tried to publish it using ClickOnce, but the haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml file is always missing. I have a relative path to this file in the program and it is located in the Resources folder. I have set the properties of the .xml file as build action content and copy if newer. I really dont know where is the problem because the haarcascade file is in publish folder in format .deploy. I attach screenshot of my application files folder[Application files folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg2no.png) in publish folder and generated folder from setup.exe in AppData/Local/Apps. You can see the haarcascade file is missing in Apps folder.[Apps folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHujA.png)

I would be very grateful if someone could help me :)

Comment: Change the mode of the project to Release and then copy the xml file to the bin sub folder of the Release folder and then hit build.

Comment: Note that you can add a file resource as well. You can then access its content as `string` like this: `string xml = Properties.Resources.MyFileResource;`. Or add the file to your project and set its property "Copy to Output directory` to `Copy if newer` in the properties window.